# RDLC List having group break condition not working with multiline

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rdlc, page-break, microsoft-reporting

I am using Micorosft Visual Studio 2015, C# with RDLC reports as bill printing medium.

In RDLC report, I am using `ROWNUMBER` to have page break in list.

Formula is for list group and its `ROWNUMBER(nothing)\6`. Its for 6 rows per page.

It works when a column has single line text but not when multiline text.

So its not working correctly when a column has multiline text.

How can I set page break correctly?

This is the screen when Items are printed in bill without item description.
The table shown is inside a List and list is having a group expression of `ROWNUMBER(nothing)\6`. It works fine because 6 perfect rows are available from source.

[image]

This is the screen when Items are printed in bill with item description.
Here I have stored item description with `<br/>` html tags so that it can be rendered as html in placeholder inside rdlc report. In report, when rendered, multiline item description is broken in seperate lines due to `<br/>` and this is when problem occurs. 6 line items are increased to more than 10 or 20 approximately. But `ROWNUMBER` only counts 6 rows as per datasource. And as you can see, line inside list is not extended correctly to bottom.

[image]

May I know how to solve this?

Comment: @mjwills Set page breaks correctly with lines.